# Suppressing Erlang “unused function” warnings in header files

Tags: erlang

I have a header file with some functionality in it.
It's meant to be for expandibility ;)

In this header file I use `-spec` for my functions.
Because my header file is included in more than one erl file and has some functionality which are not used by all of the erl files, I get warnings of functions not being used (which are being used but in another erl file).

For example:

I get for this example a warning for module `a` that function headerExecute is not being used and for module `c` that function headerCount is not being used.

```
%% Shell %%
BPid = b:create(),
APid = a:create(BPid),
CPid = c:create(BPid).

-module(a).
-export([create/1, count/2, stop/1]).
-export([loop/1]).
-include("header.hrl").

create(Id) ->
  spawn(?MODULE, loop, [Id]).

count(Pid, Counter) ->
  Pid!{count, Ref = make_ref(), self(), Counter},
  receive
    {Ref, Result} -> Result
  end.

stop(Pid) ->
  Pid!{stop}.

loop(Id) ->
  receive
    {count, Ref, From, Counter}
      Result = headerCount(Id, Counter),
      From!{Ref, Result},
      ?MODULE:loop(Id);
    {stop} ->
      ok;
    _ ->
      ?MODULE:loop(Id)
  end.

-define(header, header).
-spec headerCount(pid(), integer()) -> integer().
-spec headerExecute(pid(), atom()) -> no_return().

headerCount(Pid, Counter) ->
  Pid!{count, Ref = make_ref(), self(), Counter},
  receive
    {Ref, Result} -> Result
  end.

headerExecute(Pid, Cmd) ->
  Pid!{execute, Cmd}.

-module(b).
-export([create/0, stop/1]).
-export([loop/0]).

create() ->
  spawn(?MODULE, loop, []).

stop(Pid) ->
  Pid!{stop}.

loop() ->
  receive
    {count, Ref, From, Counter} ->
      From!{Ref, Counter + 1},
      ?MODULE:loop();
    {execute, Cmd} ->
      %% Execute something with the command Cmd %%
      ?MODULE:loop();
    {stop} ->
      ok;
    _ ->
      ?MODULE:loop()
  end.

-module(c).
-export([create/1, execution/2, stop/1]).
-export([loop/1]).
-include(header).

create(Id) ->
  spawn(?MODULE, loop, [Id]).

execution(Pid, Cmd) ->
  Pid!{execution, Cmd}.

stop(Pid) ->
  Pid!{stop}.

loop(Id) ->
  receive
    {execution, Cmd} ->
      headerExecute(Id, Cmd),
      ?MODULE:loop(Id);
    {stop} ->
      ok;
    _ ->
      ?MODULE:loop(Id)
  end.
```

For scalability it's not an option to export these in the erl files and exporting these functions in a header file result in errors.

How can I discard or get rid off these warnings?

EDIT: I put this functionality in the headers so that new erl modules can easily be added to the code and adjust the existing erl modules without touching the other erl modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you proven by profiling your code that having these functions in header files makes a positive difference for the performance of your application? If not, I recommend putting them into a normal module like normal functions, and that will eliminate the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nowarn_unused_function` compiler parameter in your header file.

```
-compile({nowarn_unused_function, [headerCount/2, headerExecute/2]})
```

But it doesn't have anything with scalability. You are using this word wrong.

Comment: I changed the scalability to expandability. Sorry for the miss interpretation.

Comment: You mean efficiency, isn't it? Because you can put `headerCount/2` and `headerExecute/2` into module and call it externaly.